# Magento 2 CLI commands doesn't work

Tags: magento2, redis, command-line

I am having a problem trying to migrate my magento2 board from server to my localhost, I copy the database and files I changed **app/etc/env.php** config parameters to fit with the local host, I did the changes in the database about the secures URLs.

But I can't clear the cache using the commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I obtaining:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.
```

I run:

```
php bin/magento list
```

which resulting in

```
We're sorry, an error occurred. Try clearing the cache and code generation directories. By default, they are: var/cache, var/di, var/generation, and var/page_cache.

[CredisException]
Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (111) Connection refused
```

Comment: I asume your magento is not installed correctly

Comment: ´but my page is runing online

Comment: I think you may have also copied env.php from your server which may have redis configuration details. Try removing that or copy a env.php from a default magento setup and change the DB name.

Comment: i remove redis form my env.php but now i am getting 502 error instead of a blank page

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your installation is not correct, checking the error message I can see that your `env.php` is configured to use Redis, remove the Redis configuration then run these commands:

```
# Install Composer packages
composer install

# Fix folder permissions
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento

# Obtain Magerun to perform CLI commands
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar
chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar 
alias n98="./n98-magerun2.phar"

# Clean and compile you Magento 2
n98 setup:upgrade
n98 deploy:mode:set developer
n98 setup:static-content:deploy -f
n98 setup:di:compile
n98 maintenance:disable
n98 sys:check
```

Comment: i have changed my version of php to php7.0 and my commands are working again, i ran the commands below but now i just seeing a blank page in my local browser

Comment: Run the commands that I sent, they will recompile your files and show then again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the env.php file DB Host parameter
"localhost" To "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case:

#enter redis cli

redis-cli

#flush all and exit

FLUSHALL

EXIT